# How to best fetch a cell value from excel using VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to get cells from excel into csharp but not sure what's the best variable type to read it into.

If I make the variable a string and the cell value is a double I get a parse error. If I make the variable double then when the cell is a string it wont work.

Here's the code I am running:

```
 try
 {
        string i = Globals.Sheet1.Cells[7, 7].Value;
        double num;
        if (i == null) return;

        if (double.TryParse(i, out num)) 
        {
             ...
        }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
       MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it an object, then find out the right type after you have gotten the value out of the cell.

I don't know about VSTO, but in the Excel Interop assembly, there were a `Value2` and a Text property which both returned object, and could be casted through polymorphism to the correct type. Doesn't VSTO provide those?

Comment: string foo = ((Range)MyWorksheet.Cells[2, 3]).Value2.ToString();

Comment: Though I didnt get to this SO article because of the same problem, the  .Text issue resolved a problem I had with Value2 with a DateTime stored in a cell. Instead it was returning me a double value, and using .Text.ToString() returned me the text value of the field that I wanted. I wasnt aware of the .Text property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to get the text value directly and do not want to deal with the underlying datatype for the most part. I get the text value as TravisWhidden comment mentioned, here is my VSTO C# code to achieve a read from a cell and return a text value regardless of the base object.

This my extension method which works off of the Worksheet page:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

public static string CellGetStringValue(this Excel.Worksheet theSheet,
                                        int row, int column)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    if (theSheet != null)
    {
        var rng = theSheet.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range;
                
        if (rng != null)
            result = (string) rng.Text;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Same but using null propagation and pattern matching

```
public static string CellGetStringValue(this Excel.Worksheet theSheet, 
                                        int row, int column)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    if (theSheet?.Cells[row, column] is Excel.Range rng)
         result = (string)rng.Text;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @TravisWhidden I took your comment as advice and created an extension to use `Text` to get a value; then posted it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
 {

    dynamic mycell = Globals.Sheet1.Cells[7, 7];
    double num;
    if (mycell.Value == null) return; //you can use mycell.Text too.

    if (double.TryParse(mycell.Text, out num)) 
    {
          .
          .
          .
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
       MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call ToString() on the object and then do double.TryParse() to see if the value is numeric or text

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
double x = (double)Globals.Sheet1.Cells[7, 7].Value;
```

will get you the double value or throw an exception (no need to catch it, it will be displayed properly in a dialog box in Excel if nothing catches it upstream).