# How to bind a VSTO Excel Add In to a DataSet (.XSD)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, excel-2016

I inherited a project from a previous developer and I am making some code adjustments. Unfortunately the way he did it wont work for my new requirements.

I have created a XSD (C# Dataset object) and filled it from the database.
Verified the data is actually pulling from the database and is populated in the dataset.

What is the best way to bind that dataset to the whole sheet to display the data. I have seen many online examples of how to bind a dataset to a List Object or other controls but how about simply dumping it to a Excel sheet. How can I get a reference to the workbook/worksheet to set the datasource.

Comment: Is there any property of the sheet, or workbook where I can set it to a dataset as a datasource or is this really the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding is a relative term based on WPF or WinForms experience, a better way may be to think of it as *publishing* and *extracting* instead to avoid confusion.

---

**Method**

Only you know the data, but its best to loop through the data into an array which will contain the rows and columns for the data.

Once the array is complete, then publish to the page. Here is some base code I have used.

---

**Example**

```
public static int LastRow { get; set; }
public static int LastColumn { get; set; }

public static void PublishToSheet(this WorksheetBase theSheet, 
                                  int startRow, 
                                  int startColumn, 
                                  ref string[,] OutputArray)
{

    var totalRows  = OutputArray.GetLength(0);
    var maxColumns = OutputArray.GetLength(1);

    var range = theSheet.Range[theSheet.Cells[startRow, startColumn], 
                               theSheet.Cells[startRow + totalRows - 1,
                                              startColumn + maxColumns - 1]
                              ];
    range.NumberFormat = "@";
    range.Value2 = OutputArray;

    LastRow   = totalRows;
    LastColumn = maxColumns;

}
```

I have the properties of `LastRow` and `LastColumn` to allow me to further work with the page on other data needs to be appended.

**Usage**

```
string[,] OutputArray = new string[2, 2];

OutputArray[0, 0] = "Alpha";
OutputArray[0, 1] = "Beta";
OutputArray[1, 0] = "Gamma";
OutputArray[1, 1] = "Delta";

this.PublishToSheet(10, 4, ref OutputArray);
```

---

To extract data see my response to [How to best fetch a cell value from excel using VSTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726947/285795)

Comment: Thank you for your info. I will look into it this way.